# Unable to link 2 HTML pages by express.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am unable to link my predict.html page and index.html. Whenever start button is clicked, I do not get any error, but I also do not get redirected to the desired page

Here is my code

**index.html**

```
   <body>
        <!-- The Navbar Section -->
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li class="Mouse" style="padding-left:30px ;"><a href="#" class="heading">Bull-Dozer Price Predictor</a></li>
            
            
                <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li style="float:right"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  


        <!-- The Header Section -->
         <div style="padding:10%;">
            <h1 style="font-size:5em ;">  The Bull-Dozer Price <br> Predictor</h1>

            <form method="post">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg start" style="color: white; width: 150px; font-size: 2em;"> Start</button>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Here is app.js file

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");



const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req,res){

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/predict.html");

});



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(req,res){
    console.log("Server running on port 3000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing you not add a "__dirname +" at express static try below code

```
  const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/predict.html");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(req,res){
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but sir it is not working